# Replacing column values based on a corresponding column r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have about 60 different columns, 30 columns corresponding to the rest 30 columns by name. I want to replace these 30 column values based on the other corresponding values.

1. Sample data:

```
df.wide<-data.frame(
  title=c("A","B","C","D"),
  IM.A=c(0.5,0.1,4.6,5.6),
  LV.A=c(0.7,0,2.5,5),
  IM.B=c(0.2,0.4,2.6,2.2),
  LV.B=c(1,2,4.5,5),
  IM.C=c(2,1,3,4),
  LV.C=c(3,2,5,1)
)
```

I have more columns - IM.D~~ LM.D~~ for each title in the data.

2. I have reshaped the data to long to extract unique column names:

```
df.long <- gather(df.wide, element,value, IM.A:LV.C)
df.long <- select(df.long, c("element"))
df.long <- unique(df.long)
```

3. I've separated LV and IM into different data.

```
lv <- as.data.frame(df.long[grep("LV", df.long$element), ])
im <- as.data.frame(df.long[grep("IM", df.long$element), ])
```

4. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, but basically I want to change column LV values to 0 if its' corresponding IM values are less than 2.5 and I've not yet to find the solution on Internet.

The final data would look something like this:

```
df.wide<-data.frame(
  title=c("A","B","C","D"),
  IM.A=c(0.5,0.1,4.6,5.6),
  LV.A=c(0,0,2.5,5),
  IM.B=c(0.2,0.4,2.6,2.2),
  LV.B=c(0,0,4.5,0),
  IM.C=c(2,1,3,4),
  LV.C=c(0,0,5,1)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe put your data in long form:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.wide)

dt.long = melt(df.wide, meas=patterns(IM = "^IM", LV = "^LV"))
dt.long[, variable := c("A","B","C")[variable]]

    title variable  IM  LV
 1:     A        A 0.5 0.7
 2:     B        A 0.1 0.0
 3:     C        A 4.6 2.5
 4:     D        A 5.6 5.0
 5:     A        B 0.2 1.0
 6:     B        B 0.4 2.0
 7:     C        B 2.6 4.5
 8:     D        B 2.2 5.0
 9:     A        C 2.0 3.0
10:     B        C 1.0 2.0
11:     C        C 3.0 5.0
12:     D        C 4.0 1.0
```

From here, it is easy to make the edit:

```
dt.long[IM < 2.5, LV := 0]
```

*If you want to use tidyr*: As far as I know, `gather` does not support creating two columns when converting to long form. The next generation of the function, `pivot_longer` might.

---

I would suggest continuing to work with the data in long format as long as possible to avoid further fiddling with variable names, but if you need to get back to wide format, there's...

```
res = dcast(dt.long, title ~ variable, value.var=c("IM", "LV"), sep=".")

   title IM_A IM_B IM_C LV_A LV_B LV_C
1:     A  0.5  0.2    2  0.0  0.0    0
2:     B  0.1  0.4    1  0.0  0.0    0
3:     C  4.6  2.6    3  2.5  4.5    5
4:     D  5.6  2.2    4  5.0  0.0    1
```

Further steps are needed if you want the same column order:

```
setcolorder(res, names(df.wide))

   title IM.A LV.A IM.B LV.B IM.C LV.C
1:     A  0.5  0.0  0.2  0.0    2    0
2:     B  0.1  0.0  0.4  0.0    1    0
3:     C  4.6  2.5  2.6  4.5    3    5
4:     D  5.6  5.0  2.2  0.0    4    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifelse(df.wide$IM.A < 2.5, 0, df.wide$LV.A)`.

Assuming your variables are spaced in the manner you described in `df.wide` (`IM.x` and `LV.x` all follow each other) for all columns you could do something like this, where 3 is the first `LV` column, and 7 is the last `LV` column.

```
df.wide[,seq(3,7, by = 2)] <- sapply(seq(3,7, by = 2), function(x)
  ifelse(df.wide[,x-1] < 2.5, 0, df.wide[,x])  
)
```

But as @Frank points out, you really should stay in long-format for a long as possible to make these sorts of operations much simpler.

Comment: Or indexing by a T/F matrix `df.wide[grep("LV", names(df.wide))][ df.wide[grep("IM", names(df.wide))] < 2.5 ] <- 0`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using the development `tidyr` `pivot_` functions. You can get these by running `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")`.

This showcases the `spec` feature of the pivot functions, which allow you to flexibly specify a reshaping format. The way it works is that each row of the spec is an input column of the original dataframe (if using `pivot_longer`). The `.name` column has the input column names, the `.value` column has the names of the new columns that you want the values from the respective input columns to go into. Here, we want to put all values from columns starting with `"IM"` into an `IM` column, and similarly for `LV`. Finally, we specify how the other variables map to columns (here it is just `letter`).

This lets us quickly `pivot_longer`, do the desired replacement with `if_else`, and then `pivot_wider` back to the original format.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df.wide <- data.frame(
  title = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  IM.A = c(0.5, 0.1, 4.6, 5.6),
  LV.A = c(0.7, 0, 2.5, 5),
  IM.B = c(0.2, 0.4, 2.6, 2.2),
  LV.B = c(1, 2, 4.5, 5),
  IM.C = c(2, 1, 3, 4),
  LV.C = c(3, 2, 5, 1)
)

spec <- tibble(
  `.name` = df.wide %>% select(-title) %>% colnames(),
  `.value` = str_extract(`.name`, "^.{2}"),
  letter = str_extract(`.name`, ".{1}$")
)

df.wide %>%
  pivot_longer(spec = spec) %>%
  mutate(LV = if_else(IM < 2.5, 0, LV)) %>%
  pivot_wider(spec = spec)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   title  IM.A  LV.A  IM.B  LV.B  IM.C  LV.C
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.5   0     0.2   0       2     0
#> 2 B       0.1   0     0.4   0       1     0
#> 3 C       4.6   2.5   2.6   4.5     3     5
#> 4 D       5.6   5     2.2   0       4     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>